# Save String and Import at Later Date

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with determining how I can save text that users enter into Textboxes and then retrieve that information later on specific dates. For example:

Day 1:

```
firstNametextbox.text = "John"
lastNametextbox.text = "Smith"
```

Day 2:

```
firstNametextbox.text = "Jim"
lastNametextbox.text = "Smith"
```

Day 3:

```
firstNametextbox.text = "Jacob"
lastNametextbox.text = "Smith"
```

On the fourth day I'd like the user to click a button and return just the results from Day 1, on the fifth day return the results from Day 1 and Day 2, etc.

I tried allowing the user to assign a date to the Day using a DateTimePicker and then checking to see if three days had passed. I also tried messing around with the Application Settings so that I could save information but it didn't seem very efficient. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First off, you want some way to store the data: mysql, sqlite, mssql express, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the AppSettings Container for it. You can just save the date in a key and every time you open the application you can retrieve it easily.

```
 ApplicationDataContainer AppSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;


            if(date1 == true && AppSettings.Values.ContainsKey("Name1") )
            {
                IsSoundOn = AppSettings.Values["Name1"].ToString();
            }
```